# Word for a story that keeps the reader's attention

Tags: single-word-requests

The word for a story or article that is keeping the reader's attention.

Example sentence:

> I would like to rewrite this story to make it more ...

Comment: to make it more interesting...

Comment: Gripping, enticing, tantalizing, compelling, fascinating, intriguing, riveting, spellbinding... Seriously, if you can't think of a word for this on your own, then you probably have no business rewriting the story.  Consuming, enthralling, exciting, arresting, alluring, captivating, bewitching, enrapturing... The possibilities are myriad and seemingly endless.

Comment: Riveting. . . .

Comment: @anemone I almost finished my answer with a **page turner** before I saw your link.  I am voting to close it. :-)

Comment: @Rathony Oh well. I actually found that post by searching for page-turner in our posts.

Comment: @anemone Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Compelling](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compelling)  or engaging*** may convey the idea:

> - having a powerful and irresistible effect: *a compelling drama.*

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

That is a ***gripping*** story. From the verb [***grip***, defined in Merriam-Webster as:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gripping)

> **2 :** to hold the interest of strongly < a story that grips the reader >

So your example would read:

> I would like to rewrite this story to make it more gripping.

Answer (score 1):

**Fascinating**

Fascinate:

> attract the strong attention and interest of (someone).

Answer (score 1):

***Riveting***

absolutely fascinating; enthralling

***A page-turner*** (... to make it more of a page-turner).

a book so exciting or gripping that one is compelled to read it very rapidly.

[enter link description here](http://from%20the%20Online%20Dictionary%20collection)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the word *riveting.*

If you are not familiar with the word *rivet*, a rivet is a metal fastener with a welder joins two pieces of steel together under extreme heat. The bond thus formed is designed to be permanent.

If your story keeps and holds your readers' attention, it fastens itself to the reader and won't let go! In other words, the story gets and keeps the audience's attention.

> I would like to rewrite this story to make it more riveting.